# Integrity Measurement Architecture(IMA) & Linux Extended Verification Module (EVM)

Tags: security, linux-kernel, cryptography, hmac

I am trying to activate IMA appraisal & EVM modules.

After compiling linux kernel 3.10.2 on my bt5R3 and setting kernel boot option in a first time like this:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=i_version ima_tcb ima_appraise=fix ima_appraise_tcb evm=fix"
```

and after running this command to generate xattr security.ima and security.evm

```bsh
find / \( -fstype rootfs -o -fstype ext4 \) -type f -uid 0 -exec head -c 1 '{}' \;
```

like this:

```bsh
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=i_version ima_tcb ima_appraise=enforce ima_appraise_tcb evm=enforce"
```

I try to create digital signature of xattr like it's recommended on this tutorial
[Tutorial to IMA & EVM](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linux-ima/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Every steps have been followed, creating RSA keys, loading them early at boot in initramfs with keyctl.

```bsh
Session Keyring
       -3 --alswrv      0 65534  keyring: _uid_ses.0
977514165 --alswrv      0 65534   \_ keyring: _uid.0
572301790 --alswrv      0     0       \_ user: kmk-user
126316032 --alswrv      0     0       \_ encrypted: evm-key
570886575 --alswrv      0     0       \_ keyring: _ima
304346597 --alswrv      0     0       \_ keyring: _evm
```

However as soon as I reboot my OS when I try to read a signed and hashed file I get the error "Permission Denied"
Running dmesg tells me :

```bsh
[ 5461.175996] type=1800 audit(1375262160.913:57): pid=1756 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 op="appraise_data" cause="**invalid-HMAC**" comm="sh" name="/root/Desktop/new.sh" dev="sda1" ino=546526 res=0
```

Have you any idea why i get invalid HMAC ? 
They keys are loaded like the tutorial says...

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -e

PREREQ=""

# Output pre-requisites
prereqs()
{
        echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

grep -q "ima=off" /proc/cmdline && exit 1

mount -n -t securityfs securityfs /sys/kernel/security

IMA_POLICY=/sys/kernel/security/ima/policy
LSM_POLICY=/etc/ima_policy

grep -v "^#" $LSM_POLICY >$IMA_POLICY

# import EVM HMAC key
keyctl show |grep -q kmk || keyctl add user kmk "testing123" @u
keyctl add encrypted evm-key "load `cat /etc/keys/evm-key`" @u
#keyctl revoke kmk

# import Module public key
mod_id=`keyctl newring _module @u`
evmctl import /etc/keys/pubkey_evm.pem $mod_id

# import IMA public key
ima_id=`keyctl newring _ima @u`
evmctl import /etc/keys/pubkey_evm.pem $ima_id

# import EVM public key
evm_id=`keyctl newring _evm @u`
evmctl import /etc/keys/pubkey_evm.pem $evm_id

# enable EVM
echo "1" > /sys/kernel/security/evm

# enable module checking
#echo "1" > /sys/kernel/security/module_check
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, new kernel use HMAC v2 and you have to activate asymmetric key when you compile kernel.

cat .config should have this entries:

```
CONFIG_EVM_HMAC_VERSION=2
CONFIG_ASYMMETRIC_KEY_TYPE=y
```

Then when you hash or sign a file use

```
evmctl -u - -x --imasig/--imahash $file
```

As well you should have create the asymetric keys and load them in _evm and _ima keyring with keyctl with initramfs.